# Fixed points of x sin 1/x

Tags: equation-solving

What is the best way to find all the fixed points of f(x)=x sin 1/x? I know it has infinitely many fixed points, so there would in theory be infinitely many outputs. What can Mathematica do about this? I have tried the following code below:

```
orbit[f4_, x_, n_] := NestList[f4, x, n]

f4[x_] := Piecewise[{{x Sin (1/x), -1 <= x < 0 || 0 < x <= 1}}, 0]

NSolve[x == f4[x], x]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! Have you tried `Piecewise[{{x Sin [(1/x)], -1 <= x < 0 || 0 < x <= 1}}, 0] `? As you have written it, your definition of `f4` contains a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't describe the problem you are having with the code you have, but I think I can guess. In Mathematica, functions like `Sin` [use square brackets `[]` to delineate arguments](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Syntax.html). So your definition of your function `f4` should be:

```
 f4[x_] := Piecewise[{{x Sin [(1/x)], -1 <= x < 0 || 0 < x <= 1}}, 0]
```

You can then get a useful answer from `NSolve`:

```
NSolve[x == f4[x], x]

(* {{x -> 0}, {x ->  ConditionalExpression[2./(
    3.14159 +  12.5664 C[1]), (C[1] \[Element] Integers && 
    C[1] >= 0) || (C[1] \[Element] Integers && C[1] <= -1.)]}} *)
```

You can even get a nice analytical answer out of `Solve`:

```
In[5]:= Solve[x == f4[x], x]

(* {{x -> 0}, {x ->  ConditionalExpression[
2/(π +  4 π C[1]), (C[1] \[Element] Integers && 
   C[1] >= 0) || (C[1] \[Element] Integers && C[1] <= -1)]}} *)
```

I don't know what the `orbit` function is doing. It seems superfluous to your problem. But it does raise another syntax issue. In a function definition, the label you use is just a [pattern label](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html). There is no relationship between the `f4` you use to name the argument of `orbit` and the `f4` you subsequently define. If you expect them to be the same automatically, you will get into trouble.

Comment: The `orbit` function was just what we defined in my class. An "orbit" is defined (in our class) to be a sequence of iterations.

Comment: Okay, I fixed my parentheses to brackets. It works now, and I got the same analytical expression you got! That shows there are infinitely many fixed points of f(x)=x sin(1/x).

Comment: @user34624 - it just wasn't clear why you needed to iterate it.